# IO exception while creating file on android sdcard with permissions granted

Tags: android, file, android-permissions, android-sdcard, sd-card

I am trying to move file from internal phone memory to sd card.

```
val oldFile = File(oldPath) //oldPath is string
val newFile = File(newPath) //newPath is string

if(newFile.exists()) {
    newFile.delete()
}

newFile.parentFile.mkdirs()
newFile.createNewFile() //crashes here

// copy file code
```

Paths are absolute.

Old file path is:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.package/files/2ec37ce3-ca72-4a35-a6e6-2d7f8e864c6c
```

New file path is:

```
/storage/48EE-C144/chosenDirectory/2ec37ce3-ca72-4a35-a6e6-2d7f8e864c6c
```

where `2ec37ce3-ca72-4a35-a6e6-2d7f8e864c6c` is file.

Paths are proper and the new file path is chosen manually by user with external directory picker library which works fine.

Of course app asks user for permissions and does not shall pass user to app until permissions are not granted.

```
int perm = this.checkSelfPermission(permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
int perm2 = this.checkSelfPermission(permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

if (perm != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || perm2 != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    /*ask for permissions and show explain dialog*/
}
```

Parmissions in manifest are added too.

Application crashes while calling `newFile.createNewFile()` with exception log:

```
05-07 13:02:14.995 14004-14004/com.packagename E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.packagename, PID: 14004
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1451)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1563)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1451) 
     Caused by: java.io.IOException: Permission denied
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively0(Native Method)
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(UnixFileSystem.java:280)
        at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:948)
        at com.packagename.backend.localApi.changePath.PathChanger.changePath(PathChanger.kt:29)
        at com.packagename.backend.localApi.changePath.PathChangeService$changePath$1.onSelect(PathChangeService.kt:49)
        at com.codekidlabs.storagechooser.fragments.ChooserDialogFragment$1.onItemClick(ChooserDialogFragment.java:169)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:343)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1665)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:4075)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$10.run(AbsListView.java:6552)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6816)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1563) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1451)
```

Comment: I've heard that there is no possibility to save data on removable sd card. But I've seen many apps that are able to.

Comment: "Paths are proper and the new file path is chosen manually by user with external directory picker library which works fine" -- I don't know what you mean by that. [Apps do not have arbitrary read/write filesystem access to removable storage on Android 4.4+](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/15/storage-situation-removable-storage.html).

Comment: I mean that the are OK and should work and there is no problem with them.

Comment: According to your question, there *is* a problem with them. Use `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` and the rest of the Storage Access Framework to allow the user to choose a location into which you can stream some content. Or, stick to `getExternalFilesDirs()`, `getExternalCacheDirs()`, and `getExternalMediaDirs()`, which will return filesystem locations on removable storage (2nd array element) that you have read/write access to.

Comment: So concluding, it is not possible to operate on files (copy, move) with absolute paths?

Comment: Not in the way that you are doing it. There may be a few devices that support such access, but they are in violation of the Compatibility Definition Document rules, and so you should not assume that *arbitrary* devices support such access. Another option, BTW, if your `minSdkVersion` is 24+, is to [use `createAccessIntent()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/storage/StorageVolume.html#createAccessIntent(java.lang.String)), though this is in the same vein as the `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` approach.

Comment: `48EE-C144` - I don't think that this is correct derectory name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for me was stop using java classes and migrate to [Storage Access Framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider)

Answer (score 4):

Need to add permission in **AndroidManifest.xml** file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: OS 6.0 or above?

Comment: It's samsung galaxy j5 with android 7.1.1. And api in gradle are set to:   `minSdkVersion 21` and  `targetSdkVersion 27`

Comment: Need to add dynamic permission for Marshmallow (7.0) and above.

Comment: I said in question that if user will not allow app access storage, he will not be able to enter app.

Comment: OP says permission was added. I actually have the same problem, but this doesn't answer he question.